# How to upload a zip files in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, file-upload, zip

I'm trying to upload a zip files but I'm getting some error and I want to display the images inside of it. This is my code this is my code:

**Controller**

```
$config['upload_path'] = './img/header/';   
$config['allowed_types'] = 'rar|zip|gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
$config['max_size'] = '2048000';
$config['overwrite'] = TRUE;          

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">', '</div>');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Name', 'trim|required');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE || !$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) { 
    $this->load->view('plmar/admin/headContent');
} else {
    $content = array(
        'header_title' => $_POST['title'],
        'header_path' => $_POST['userfile'],
        'upload_data' => $this->upload->data()
    );

    $this->adminModel->addContent($content);
    redirect('Administrator/headContent');
}

$this->load->view('admin/footer');
```

Comment: Paste code as text not image.

Answer (score 0):

just add * 
for Ex : `$config['allowed_types'] = '*';` and remove this `$config['allowed_types'] = 'rar|zip|gif|jpg|png|jpeg';`

Comment: I changed it to * and theres an error.. How should i call it in my view?